# Adding Concrete.class to a Collection<Class<Abstract>>

Tags: java, inheritance, collections, abstract-class

Hi Team,

I want to create a collection of concrete class objects, that extend a common Abstract class or interface.

- `c1` allows me to store concrete instances that extend the abstract class.
- `c2` allows me to store concrete instances of any class with no control of what goes in the collection.
- `c3` Is what I thought I thought I wanted, but it is actually a collection of `AbstractTest` and I can't place concrete class into the collection.

  ```
  Collection<AbstractTest> c1 = new HashSet<AbstractTest>();
  c1.add(new TestImpl());

  Collection<Class<?>> c2 = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
  c2.add( TestImpl.class);

  Collection<Class<AbstractTest>> c3 = new HashSet<Class<AbstractTest>>();
  c3.add( TestImpl.class); <<< ERRORS!!!!
  ```

How can I achieve what I am after?

---

### EDIT

```
Collection<Class<? extends AbstractTest>> c3 = 
                             new HashSet<Class< ? extends  AbstractTest>>();
    c3.add(TestImpl.class);
```

Comment: use <? extends AbstractTest>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collection<Class<? extends AbstractTest>>` is what you want.

```
Collection<Class<? extends AbstractTest>> c3 = new HashSet<Class<? extends AbstractTest>>();
c3.add(TestImpl.class);
```

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError Please post it in your original question.

Comment: @AnotherCompilerError Have a closer look, that's different ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Use extends like `ArrayList<? extends Number> list;`, in which you can put Number and any subclasses of it.

Comment: Why do you add a class to the collection? "a collection of concrete class objects": Use `c3.add(new TestImpl());`

Comment: I'm calling a new instance of them later, with reflection.